# php array to javascript array (called from a function)

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have an array in php file test.php; I need it in Javascript array.

```
<?php 
$phpArray = glob('*.jpg');
echo json_encode($phpArray);
?>
```

I need each filename in Javascript array so I can access it like:

```
myJavasciptArray[0];
```

I need to get my JavaScript array loaded from the function:

```
$("#button2").click(function(){
$.get("test.php",function(data){
var mypics=data;
  alert(mypics[1]);      
});
});
```

but what I get instead of each filename in the array is a character.

```
myJavasciptArray[0]="["
```

instead of:

```
myJavasciptArray[0]="myfile1.jpg"
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of using `jQuery.get()`, use `jQuery.getJson()` and you should be fine. If you don't, `myJavascriptArray` is a string, and `someString[0]` means the first letter of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting result as JSON type.

Add `json` dataType to your `$.get()` so result is parsed as JSON:

```
$("#button2").click(function(){
   $.get("test.php",function(data){
      var mypics=data;
      alert(mypics[1]);      
   }, 'json');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) here :

```
$.get("test.php",function(data){
    var mypics = JSON.parse(data);
    alert(mypics[1]);      
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you getting is a string back from the request, you will need to use JSON.parse() function to get the correct json object

```
var mypics = JSON.parse(data)
```